# change resources url to lowercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess

we had project for maintenance and there is one serious issue.

**for site logo they write image url like: images/imageName.png**

but actual image store in folder is **image/imagename.png**

so is there any way to reload resource using any script or htaccess code which reload all resource with all lower case ?

**code use in html**

```
<img alt="logo" src="images/imageName.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all the images that need lowercase css class toLowerCase

```
<img class="toLowerCase" alt="logo" src="images/imageName.png"> // Will change
<img class="toLowerCase" alt="logo" src="images/imageDate.png"> // Will change
<img class="toLowerCase" alt="logo" src="images/imageTest.png"> // Will change
<img  alt="logo" src="images/THISWONTCHANGE.png"> // Wont change

$('img.toLowerCase').each(function () {
    var sourceName = $(this).attr('src').toLowerCase();
    $(this).attr('src', sourceName);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h468bd2g/2/

If this is it, press the green tick.

Comment: Can you please narrow down your answer or provide some code?

Comment: but i apply this script to all image tag, it will become mess cause some image name are in upper case and we cant change it.

so i want case insensitive resource load using htaccess.

Comment: How is that? You need to give each image you want to make lowerCase a class and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this server-side when you write your links in whatever programming language you are using. However if that is not an option, see solution below.

You might want to use `.htaccess` to automatically redirect upperCase url to lowerCase ones. Please take a look at [apache htaccess documentation](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase.html) for this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: i had use this way, but it convert all resource with lower case.

we want load resource with case insensitive names.